# Can I put heavy keyboard on the macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I recently bought [Massdrop Alt High Profile keyboard](https://drop.com/buy/massdrop-alt-high-profile-mechanical-keyboard). It's pretty heavy at 43oz or 1.3Kg (the weight equal two or three normal mechanical keyboards).

My question is, can I put it on the MacBook Pro so that I can use it with Magic Trackpad (not put on the screen)? Will it damage MacBook pro?

Comment: "weight of a normal mechanical keyboard" is how much exactly?  I'm getting a Unicomp buckling spring keyboard for my Mac and it's 7 pounds (3.2kg).  An A1048 (clear) keyboard is probably 4 to 5 pounds.  So, are you saying you want to put something that weighs from 8 to 21 pounds (3.6kg to 9.5kg) on top of your MacBook Pro?  Is it worth the risk?

Comment: 43 oz (1,219 g)

Comment: What weight is that?  Mechanical keyboard or your Massdrop?

Comment: the keyboard's weight is 1.2kg

Answer (score 1):

The weight of the keyboard is one thing.  I have seen students put a stack of textbooks on top of their MacBook laptops without any damage.  I can't tell you what the weight was nor do I want to embark on a testing procedure to find out what its weight tolerance is.

However, what I have found is that it's not so much the weight, but the *activity* that impacts the MacBook.  I have seen MacBook laptops used as everything from a cafeteria tray to a seat cushion to even a mirror for putting on makeup.  These machines were returned to our depot for repair because of what they was *done* to them, not what was placed on them.

In your case, you want to use this as a keyboard stand for a mechanical keyboard (gaming perhaps?) so you will be "pounding" on this keyboard for any length of time.

The (rethorical) question is - is this worth it?  Is a damaged top case worth this activity?  I can tell you that these assemblies (keyboard, case, track pad, etc.)  are not covered under Apple warranty when damaged and it's quite expensive to repair.  I'd find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the case for this being good, since most of the time you want the keyboard on a surface lower than the screen - I'd prop the Mac on something behind the keyboard and get a Magic Trackpad or mouse of your choosing so your hands can be all on a lower plane than the Mac. (get the [Twelve South curve](https://www.twelvesouth.com/products/curve-for-macbook) if you can)

[image: Twelve South curve stand]

Also, you'll want to control for any case where the lid shuts - since I've seen all sorts of damage where no-one intended for the lid to shut, yet it does. That keyboard will damage the hinge or crack the glass in a fraction of a heartbeat due to the leverage the screen will exert on the part that pinches by the hinges.

Damage due to rubbing / pressure on the case is the last of your worries in my experience. The unibody construction is very solid and if you truly want the keyboard on top of the Mac, you could easily make shims on the left and right to attack to your solid keyboard so they press on the same surface as the Mac and not use the Mac top case as the surface to press.

Comment: Thank you! But the keyboard isn't that long.

Comment: @IntellijIDEA sounds like making a shim would be the only option, then. Good luck adapting your hardware to your wetware and hands.