# Block a built-in keyboard in macOS 10.15.6

Tags: keyboard, applications, catalina, script

I'm looking for some tool that would turn off a built-in MBP keyboard. I would like to put my Planck on it.

I've already tried:

- Krabinier's disabled keyboard. Not an option. Karabinier interferes with my QMK one-shot modifiers or something.
- Command `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/`
  Used it. Don't work on 10.15.6(19G73). Before and after restart.

Do you know any other tricks, app or script?

Comment: It seems several people are thinking this would be good to have. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380202/can-i-put-heavy-keyboard-on-the-macbook-pro

Comment: It's a USB keyboard and directly connected to the USB bus.  Even if you do disable it, if the USB bus resets (and it does), it will redirect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked Karabinier once again and I found a solution that will block build-in keyboard without messing QMK's OSM.

1. Disable a built-in keyboard when external is plugged. For me it's Planck EZ.
   [image]
2. Be sure to also uncheck events modification in the "basic configuration" tab for the same keyboard.
   [image]

That configuration seems to work for me.